# how does capacitor work ? how do they conduct electricity ?

Tags: capacitor

Sorry, i am novice in electronics, trying to understand basic fundamental of electronics. 
1. How does capacitor conduct current when two plates aren't physically connected.

Comment: This is a very broad question - you should start with the Wikipedia page on caps, or some of the plenty of the other information on caps available online.  But the specific question about current 'through' caps (which have isolated plates) is very interesting.  I found this video helpful in explaining that.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppWBwZS4e7A

Comment: 'how do they conduct electricity ?' ..... yeah... the thing is, that kinda depends on what you think 'electricity' is:(  Movement of charge, or transfer of energy, particles or fields, both, neither.  Really, you have to get those concepts down first:)

Comment: The truth of the matter is that they don't conduct current, as normally understood. They conduct ['displacement current'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current), a concept introduced by Maxwell to make his equations work. How the capacitors found out about Maxwell and started obeying his equations is another question ;-)

Comment: LOL @EJP Because they are Maxwell "SMART' perhaps... (1965 sitcom reference for those are not as old as dirt like me..)

Comment: There are also a ton of good write-ups, videos, etc. in search results for ["how do capacitors work"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20do%20capacitors%20work).

Comment: They can store electrical charges which can be released at later time. Like a temporary storage.

Answer (score 12):

It's like a flexible diaphram in-line with water flow in a pipe that conducts water.  It can't indefinitely, but it can allow water to flow back and forth a limited amount.

The insulator in a capacitor is like the diaphram in that no charges can pass.  However, charges do pile up on both sides of the insulator so that current can flow up to a certain point, or back and forth current can flow.

The amount of charge that has to build up to get to a certain voltage (pressure across the diaphram) is proportional to that voltage.  That proportionality constant is the capacitance.  A higher capacitance is like a looser diaphram in-line with water flow.

Comment: I like this analogy Olin

Comment: Still then i don't understand how the electrons flows in the other end of the capacitor.

Comment: Probably the best analogy for a beginner, but this will leave the OP wondering how can a capacitor still work when there is no dielectric material between the plates. Can displacement current be explained at this level (without Maxwell's eqs)?

Comment: @SredniVashtar what does 'no dielectric material between the plates' mean?  Wouldn't that imply the plates are shorted together?

Comment: @AngeloQ I mean in the vacuum. No matter, only empty space.

Comment: @SredniVashtar when you get to that point, the only recourse is maths, ie the dreaded Maxwell's :(

Comment: @Sredni: First, at the level the OP is clearly at, anything beyond a simple analogy will confuse rather than illuminate.  It's not useful to try to go further in this question.  Even bringing it up will just add confusion.  Second, I deliberately said "insulator", and a vacuum is a great insulator.

Comment: Minor typo: there's a "g" in diaphragm

Comment: @DipankarRout: The electrons don't flow to the other side. Instead ANOTHER law of physics start applying to the situation. The electrons will gather up on one side because it can't get to the other. What does physics say about negative charge? They repel each other. Because a lot of electrons collect on one side it forces the electrons on the other side away. This tiny movement is what you measure as current and as Olin mentioned it can't last long (in most circuits the "current" typically last less than one second before it can't flow anymore)

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I might agree with the confusing part (even though I believe it's better to know the whole story and not understanding it *yet*, than believing to know the whole story). I am not so sure the vacuum is an insulator tout-court. For electrical and thermal conduction, it has to be, of course. But if you decide to go ballistic (i.e 'vacuum tubes' - they do pass a current, don't they? As a matter of fact they do need a 'good vacuum' to work) or count radiation in, well there goes your insulation. At the level the OP is clearly at, that could confuse him.

Answer (score 10):

Charges don't flow *through* the capacitor. Current flow isn't so much the passing of one electron from one side of a conductor to the other as it is one electron pushing the next in line. Consider a tube filled with ping pong balls. If you push one in at one end, you'll see one pop out of the other end. Is it the same ping pong ball you just pushed in? No, but it was pushed out by the rest of the balls in the tube.

Adjusting Olin's analogy a bit, if you cut the tube in half and put a piece of rubber in the middle, and glue everything back together so that it looks like the original tube, but with a rubber barrier in the center, than you have what is effectively a capacitor. If you push one ping pong ball in one end, it will push the rest of the balls, flex the rubber, and push one out on the other end. But none of the ping pong balls actually pass through the rubber. Then imagine repeating this process over and over, but alternating which end you push a ping pong ball into. You still get ping pong balls coming out the opposite end you push other ping pong balls into, but never does a single ping pong ball cross the rubber barrier.

The rubber barrier is the dielectric in the capacitor, the ping pong balls are charges, and the tube is your conductor. You can see that by applying a force (voltage potential) on one side of the conductor will still cause movement of the charges, but they will not actually flow through the capacitor. The *movement* is current, not necessarily a charge being pushed all the way through from one side to the other.

Note that this is the concept for an *ideal* capacitor, it doesn't take into account the actual storage of charge, and in reality practical capacitors are much more complex. There is no perfect insulator, and there will always be some leakage through an equivalent resistance, but hopefully this analogy helps you understand the idea of AC on a capacitor a little better.

Comment: Thank you. What a great explanation, now i understand how capacitor conducts current. But how does capacitor conducts current continuously at the other end because at some point all electrons at the apposite end will be depleted.

Comment: Not quite, charges don't just vanish. When I say a ping pong ball falls out the end I only said that to demonstrate the movement of the charges. In reality, instead of a straight tube with open ends, it's more like a round tube with the ends connected across a "pump" (the AC source) that switches the direction of moving charges. This circular tubing is considered a complete *circuit*. All of the charges stay in the tube but they are repeatedly pushed back and forth inside of it.

Comment: Okay, but how the capacitor provide constant DC supply since the dc doesn't move back and forth as Ac does. As an example, in SMPS, capacitor is being used to provide constant DC.

Comment: That has to do with the charge storage capability of a capacitor. When you apply DC to a capacitor (such as after a rectifier) positive charges begin to collect on one plate and negative charges begin to collect on the other. It's much like rubbing a balloon against your hair, and the balloon stores the charge and you can stick it to things. When you have positive charge stored on one side and negative charge stored on the other side, the capacitor acts like a battery. In a DC filtering application, it behaves like the graphic here: http://www.rcptv.com/spacetec-be/smoothng.gif .

Comment: The capacitor helps to smooth the "bumpy" AC voltage waveform that you get out of a rectifier.

Comment: A capacitor does not provide constant DC current *through* it. In fact capacitors in series with inputs are usually called "DC blocking".

Comment: @pjc50 Agreed, though the potential difference *across* the capacitor, if charged with DC and then connected to a load, does *cause* current to flow *through* the load. The analogy of the ping pong balls in the tube with the rubber barrier is a good example of DC blocking. You can push the charges only so far in one direction before they won't be able to go any further. Beyond that point they block the movement of the charges.

Comment: I like this analogy better than the water diaphragm one. It says much the same thing, but feels more natural to think about (at least to me), which is exactly what you want when trying to understand something for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Capacitors are a strange beast and the subject of many an argument between EEs.

The truth of the matter is... it's complicated.

[image]

With reference to the above image.

As you know, capacitors consist of two "plates" separated by an insulating layer which has a high leakage resistance. The electrostatic field between the plates means that **when an electron enters the right plate it forces an electron off the left plate.**

When you try to apply a voltage across the capacitor, electrons must leave the left plate and travel round the circuit to pile up on the right plate. This happens through that circuit's resistance and gives you the RC charging or discharging time constant.

As this happens, **Iin = Iout**. So looking at it as a "black box" it appears, and you can say, that current is passing "through" the capacitor though in fact, technically it is not.

The only current that ACTUALLY passes though the capacitor dielectric is the leakage current **Ileak**.

You can think of it as two tanks of water connected by a pipe.

[image]

When there is no vertical difference between the tanks there is no water flow in the pipe. When you introduce an offset to the system, water flows around the pipe from the higher side to the lower side till it comes into balance.

If you could not see the tanks, only the input and output pipes, the same amount of water is exiting the left side as is entering the right side so it "appears" as though the water is flowing through it.

Comment: What really helped me with your explanation was the mention of forces since if one has a basic understanding of atomic physics it's understood that forces between particles are exerted even with empty space between them.