# Capacitor dielectric and current flow

Tags: capacitor, current, dielectric

A capacitor has insulating material between plates and this insulting material does not provide any electrical or conducting path between capacitor plates. But still, capacitor allows DC or/and AC current to flow through it, How?

Comment: Capacitors do not allow a steady state DC current flow, and are often used for "DC blocking "

Comment: You would have easily found the answer if you tried to search  for [how does a capacitor work ?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293397/how-does-capacitor-work-how-do-they-conduct-electricity)

Comment: Ever heard of an electric field? Or magnetic field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
I think I hear the sound of a can of worms being opened.
```

It's called displacement current - it is a time varying electric field that gives rise to the same phenomena associated with regular currents. For the casual onlooker it might as well be real current.

It's embodied in Maxwell's equations.

[Wikipedia on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current)

Another electrical phenomena that apparently should have real current but doesn't is the radio wave. Again all down to Maxwell and displacement current.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the dielectric for the moment, if you build a charge on one plate it will repel similar charge from the other - basic electrostatics. That looks like a current flow. With dielectrics one typically uses a polar medium. That is, the molecules in the dielectric are asymmetically charged, so while overall being neutral one end is more positive than the other. Electrically, that makes the gap between the plates look much smaller and so increases the capacitance.

Comment: "Looks like" current?   Actually it is a current.  But it looks like charge-flow.

Answer (score 1):

One way to visualize this is to imagine as one electron is pushed onto one plate, an electron that was already existing on the other plate is pushed off.